# Does $N_{\textit{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})}(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ have an infinite number of components.

Tags: lie-groups, complex-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete co-compact subgroup of $\textit{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and let $\pi:\mathcal{X}\mapsto B$ be a deformation of the homogeneous space $\textit{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})/\Gamma$. When I compute the complex analogous of the mapping class group of fibers of $\pi$, that is $\textit{Aut}(\pi^{-1}(b))/\textit{Aut}^0(\pi^{-1}(b))$, I find that, for some $b$, it is isomorphic to the quotient of the normalizer $N_{\textit{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})}(\Gamma)$ of $\Gamma$ in $\textit{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ by $\Gamma$ itself.

My questions are :

Does $N_{\textit{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})}(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ have infinite number of component ?

Under which hypothesis on $\Gamma$ can we have infinite number of components ?

Comment: You claimed that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})/\Gamma$ was compact. $N_{SL_2(\mathbb{C})}(\Gamma)$ is a closed subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ so unless something very weird is going on I'd say we get a natural embedding of $N_{SL_2(\mathbb{C})}(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ into $SL_2(\mathbb{C})/\Gamma$ as a closed subspace. But a closed subspace of a compact space is itself compact (you know, in the ordinary world where everything is Hausdorff) and hence has finitely many components.

Comment: So in order to have infinitely many components something in the above reasoning must break down. Perhaps there are situations where modding out by $\Gamma$ destroys the Hausdorffness? I think something like that might happen if the action of $\Gamma$ is not free, but I am not sure. And even then I am not sure it will get you out of 'closed subsets of THIS PARTICULAR, still pretty nice, compact set are compact themselves'.

Comment: In short: I believe that the co-compactness of $\Gamma$ implies the the compactness (and hence having only finitely many components) of $N_{SL_2(\mathbb{C})}(\Gamma)/\Gamma$, but if you have an example of such a $\Gamma$ where you do get infinitely many components please let me know!

Comment: I think you are right. Modding out by $\Gamma$ does not destroy Hausdorffness, hence we get a good embedding in the quotient. And again you are right by saying that co-compactness of $\Gamma$ implies the compactness of the homogeneous space and therefore compactness of the complex mapping class group... I have few examples of $\Gamma$ which gives only finite number of components of $N_{\textit{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})}(\Gamma)/\Gamma$ but I hoped that it is not the general case.

Comment: Thank you for this answer !

Comment: In fact, the quotient group in your question is finite. This is because the normalizer of a discrete Zariski dense subgroup is again discrete.